# redirectMatch 301 regex is not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I want to redirect http://site.com/home?page=123 http://site.com/home
but the following rule doesnt work

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/home/\?(.*)$ http://www.site.com/
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The / after home probably ought to be optional. ^/home/?\?(.*)$

Comment: @Loveleen Kaur 1) Could you please clarify which URL you want to redirect from and what is the final URL (e.g. from => to) -- it's not really clear right now. 2) How do you want this to be done -- using Redirect/RedirectMatch directive .. or using mod_rewrite ?

Comment: @Lazyone, 1. source= www.site.com/home?page=123 destination www.site.com/ 2. As long as the redirection works, any method is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `RedirectMatch` directive does not work with query string -- only with path part of the URL. You have to use **mod_rewrite** for that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =page=123
RewriteRule ^home$ http://www.site.com/? [R=301,L]
```

1. Place it in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some tweaking may be required.
2. It will ONLY redirect request for `/home?page=123`. All other requests (e.g. `/home?page=123&extra=hello`) will be ignored.